# Connecting to an Azure MySQL Database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, azure

Here's my code to test connecting to the DB I just set up.

```
<?php
// DB connection info
$servername = "slateproject.database.windows.net";
$username = "";
$password = "";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

and the error

Connection failed: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Any clue what is preventing the connection?

Comment: if you're connecting to mysql, why are you telling pdo to use `sqlsrv` (e.g. MS Sql Server)?

Comment: What should I be using?

Comment: something appropriate for mysql...

Comment: Didn't work. I don't quite understand which PDO is appropriate for a simple connection.

Comment: Look at this http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php You need to also install the Drivers https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: I don't quite understand why I would need specific drivers when Azure is hosting everything. I edited the code and still get the same error.

Comment: Hope http://marianaggaga.azurewebsites.net/?p=2861 this will help you.  But if you would like to connect from your local pc or other ip then you need to enable that ip in remote connection section

Answer (score 0):

Your database endpoint is `database.windows.net`, and it is the common endpoint of Azure SQL Service which is based on SQLServer but MySQL.

To connect to SQL Server in PHP, we need to enable `php_sqlsrv` extension, and the connection code sample:

`<?php 
$connectionInfo = array(
                       "UID" => "<user>@ttyir96emw",
                       "pwd" => "<your_passwd>",
                       "Database" => "garytestmb_db",
                       "LoginTimeout" => 30,
                       "Encrypt" => 1
                  );
$serverName = "tcp:ttyir96emw.database.windows.net,1433";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
?>`

By the way, in [Azure manage portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/), the DASHBORAD page, we can click “Show connection string” to check the connection string and code examples in different language.

If you want to use MySQL as database,  Azure provides ClearDB as MySQL server , you can follow [How to Create a MySQL Database in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-php-create-mysql-database/) to create a MySQL database via ClearDB.

If you want to build your MySQL database in Azure VM, please refer [Install MySQL on a virtual machine created with the classic deployment model running Windows Server 2012 R2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-mysql-windows-server-2008r2/).